# Outgoing mail connection timeout for Centos 6.4 Final

Tags: centos, email, postfix, firewall, smtp

I am trying to send email from my server box and it never goes out. So I checked my mail log as below. I have never done any changes on the /etc/postfix/main.cf . My admin just gave me a host to be put into the conf. So which part of the main.cf should be edited to take this value.

```
tail -f /var/log/maillog
Mar 19 13:52:54 **** postfix/sendmail[2533]: fatal: unsupported: -bt
Mar 19 13:55:32 **** postfix/pickup[2208]: F083C2C0249: uid=0 from=<root>
Mar 19 13:55:33 **** postfix/cleanup[2543]: F083C2C0249:
message-id=<20130319055532.F083C2C0249@****>
Mar 19 13:55:33 **** postfix/qmgr[5755]: F083C2C0249:
from=<root@****>, size=435, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 19 13:56:03 **** postfix/smtp[2545]: connect to
mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.**.***]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 19 13:56:33 **** postfix/smtp[2545]: connect to
mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.**.***]:25: Connection timed out
Mar 19 13:57:03 ppnc postfix/smtp[2545]: connect to
mx4.hotmail.com[65.54.**.***]:25: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Do you have any iptables running, is selinux enabled? Can you paste your main.cf ?

Comment: Yes the iptables and selinux are running and I could not post the main.cf is too long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using sendmail, but postfix pretending to be sendmail, and postfix is telling you it does not understand -bt.

So probably you are using the wrong command to send mail (or to diagnose why you cannot send mail). Easiest will be to ask the same admin who gave you "a host to be put in the conf".

Comment: yes I am learning normally centos comes with postfix rite ? So do I need to remove postfix and install sendmail?

Comment: No, but you do need to check that your manuals, tutorials and youtube videos refer to postfix. And you might do better asking on the Unix & Linux site (http://unix.stackexchange.com/) rather than here, which is intended for professional sys admins.

Answer (score 5):

Your ISP/router may block outgoing connection to port 25 as spam prevention measure.

Can you telnet external smtp servers?

```
telnet mx1.hotmail.com 25
```

If you have been advised to relay outgoing email via smart host then configure/set relayhost option in main.cf configuration file.

```
relayhost = [gateway.example.com]
```

URL(s):

- http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost

Comment: I am trying to telnet via the shell is giving me this error telnet mx1.hotmail.com 25
-bash: telnet: command not found